# Java application throwing error after adding tomcat-embed-jasper artifact in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-14, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am getting following error after adding tomcat-embed-jasper dependency.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/Vishal/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/ecj/3.12.3/ecj-3.12.3.jar
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromUrlClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:96)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:546)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromManifestClassPathAttribute(ChangeableUrls.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:107)
... 17 more
```

I tried it in every IDE, and I am getting same error everywhere. Please help me understand the reason why. Maven automatically updates dependencies, but when I run my application I am getting the above error.

I am adding below code in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of you dependencies? You're adding jasper, so are you also configuring your application to serve JSP?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an indication of a corrupted jar. Try removing the artifact from your maven cache, or simply remove the whole cache  (`C:/Users/Vishal/.m2/repository/`) so that it is recreated from scratch.

Similar issues reported in Spring Boot project [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6417) were resolved this way.